# Вызов метода через определенное время (потоки)

Tags: java, многопоточность

Имеется задача: после выполнения определенного метода в главном потоке, запустить ожидание 10-ти секунд, а потом запустить второй метод, снова в главном потоке. При этом ожидание должно проходить не в главном потоке (как минимум, не блокировать его).

Единственный вариант, который я придумал: в конце первого метода запустить второй поток, который после 10-ти секундного ожидания - `wait(10000)`, вызовет метод в главном потоке. Но тут нюанс: а как вызвать метод в главном потоке из... не главного?)

Да и меня очень сильно терзают сомнения: а нет ли в Java стандартной функции ожидания, которой говоришь ждать какое-то время, а, спустя это время, она просто вызывает слушатель?

Как можно выполнить поставленную задачу (может можно как-то запустить метод в главном потоке из второго или у Java есть функция ожидания)?

Comment: Вот руководство по таймерам, может поможет вам http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/timer.php
Но таймер, как я понимаю, все таки создает отдельный поток

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться и что используете? Вообще, нельзя просто так взять и запустить метод в существующем потоке. Можно сделать, как в андроиде - изначально запустить в потоке [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (`Looper` в андроиде), и уже в нем из очереди забирать команды и выполнять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод с помощью *RxJava*:

```
Observable.just(true).delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                callMethod(); //Вызовется через 10 секунд
            }
        });
```

Comment: `cannot resolve metod subscribe(void)`...

Comment: @bukashka101 поправил

Comment: Все равно выдает ошибку. Я покажу свой способ, более длинный, но рабочий.

Comment: @bukashka101 моя вина, забыл уточнить, что это с лямбдами. Либо 8 Java, либо с retrolambda

Answer (score 1):

Набросал такой вариант:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestApp extends AbstractTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        first();
        second_delayed();
    }

    public static void first() {
        format("First method%n");
    }

    public static void second() {
        format("Second method%n");
    }

    public static void second_delayed() {
        format("Delayed method start%n");

        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        service.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestApp.second();
            }
        }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        format("Delayed method end%n");
    }
}
```

После вызова `second_delayed()` управление сразу возвращается в основной метод и основной поток может делать что-то другое полезное. После 10 секунд вызывается метод `second()` в отдельном потоке.

Реализация основана на статических методах, но будет несложно переписать и через не статические методы, если понадобится. Никакие дополнительные библиотеки не используются.

Comment: Да вот проблема в том, что нужно в отдельном потоке...

Comment: Что значит "В отдельном потоке"? Нужно, чтобы второй метод запустился в главном потоке? Или в каком-то третьем методе? Можете пояснить, зачем это нужно?

Comment: Ой, не то написал. Нужно чтобы оба метода работали в одном потоке. А нужно затем, что метод из библиотеке попросту не работает во втором (я на Android пишу, если что).

Comment: "я на Android пишу" - совсем маленькая деталь. Можно было бы сразу указать больше деталей о своей задаче.